# Security with PHP permissions chmod 1703

Tags: php, security, permissions, webserver, file-permissions

**Context:**
I am new to coding so apologies for any basic misunderstandings here. I am creating an online experiment using a simple interactive cognitive task. I have coded this in javascript/HTML/CSS, primarily in jsPsych. I have then put the experiment online using Qualtrics following this guide: https://kywch.github.io/jsPsych-in-Qualtrics.

**The program:**
Essentially, the data object created by jsPsych for a participant is saved with the following function in the javascript:

```
jQuery.ajax({ type: 'post', cache: false, url: save_url, data: {
                data_dir: data_dir,
                file_name: file_name + '.json',
                exp_data: jsPsych.data.get().json()
            }
        });
```

The php file linked to with save_url is as follows:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://ssd.az1.qualtrics.com');
$exp_data = $_POST['exp_data'];
$_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if (isset($_POST['data_dir']) == true)
{
    $data_dir = $_POST['data_dir']; // data directory
} else { exit; }
if (isset($_POST['file_name']) == true)
{
    $file_name = $_POST['file_name']; // mturk_id
} else { exit; }
file_put_contents($data_dir.'/'.$file_name, $exp_data);
exit;
?>
```

**The issue:**
And in the example, the directory is it writes to is encoded with `chmod 772`. Now, this doesn’t work on the webspace provided by my university. Instead, I had to give users write and execute permissions with at least `773`, although with no group members needed, `703` will also work, and perhaps a sticky bit could be added with chmod `1703`.

This is all running, but I have concerns over security and in particular GDPR compliance. I was wondering if anything stood out here as particularly problematic security wise, and if anyone had any tips or resources on how to improve this in a way that would be manageable to someone with not too much time to spend, and little knowledge on the subject.

I am currently trying to implement this method, for example: http://www.mysql-apache-php.com/fileupload-security.htm

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: The most common thing from the link at the end is *4. Place the upload folder outside WWW root.*

Comment: Make sure there is no other directory that function can write to. What happens if I choose `../../../etc/hosts` as a filename?

Comment: For directories, "execute" has a different meaning. The execute flag should definetly not be set for the files in that folder.

Comment: @JonasWilms So how would I make it so that the function can't write to another directory? perhaps the PHP file shouldn't take the folder name from qualtircs and instead the folder location should be hard coded into the PHP file?

As for your second point, if allowing executions on the directory isn't great, how could I get the program to work without this? Perhaps you have some idea about why the example program worked with only write permissions enabled but mine doesn't? From reading online, it seems perhaps I'm not the owner of the directory but my university is?

Comment: @NigelRen I can only get the program to work using this folder outside public_html with 777 permissions. Would you be able to shed any light on why this might be, and if this is more of a security issue?

Comment: Have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work

Comment: "perhaps I'm not the owner". Have you checked `ls -l` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms So that seems to suggest that the folder that houses save_data.php (exp_data) requires execute permissions only as my javascript links directly to that file, and limiting save_data.php to read only would be the best idea (see: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32148/is-making-my-php-files-read-only-a-useful-security-measure), as well as using sticky bits? As my data will upload to outside the wwwroot, there are no subdirectories or other files in exp_data.